# Which library is the best in php for making async requests

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, request

I have a lot of data, which I want to transfer to Logz.io.

Basically, the project is written in Laravel and I want to create an event manager  which will do all the job of logging info to  Logz.io. I need an advice about which library h is better to use , something like guzzle curl, which can help me to send logs info to logz.io in the  background. I mean, I don't want to wait until the request with data for logz.io will finish.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as far as I know, there are two approaches that you could take:

1) Using Laravel's [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) system to send your logs later. For this you'd have to enable a worker or a supervisor process to send them on the background.

2) There's this package by the people at spatie - [spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async) which is a wrapper around PHP's PCNTL extension and allows excecuting php code in separate threads.

I hope I could help you, even if a little.

Comment: Thank you, I've started using queue -> AWS SQS

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not an async language. Laravel has a [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) system that works out of the box.

Basically you put some jobs in a queue and another process (it can be also in another machine), run them. It will work well in your scenario because you don't need a real-time log collection but you can delegate it by few seconds.